# Problems with options on Jquery Infinite Scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I am using infinite scroll in conjunction with Jquery Masonry. Everything is working great, except I can not get any of the options to work for Infinite scroll. I am trying to change the loading text, add a bufferpx. The documentation says you can do this and I've followed it exactly but nothing changes on my site. Here is what I have:

```
$(function(){

var $container = $('#loop-wrapper');

$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.hentry'
  });
});

$container.infinitescroll({
  animate  : true,   

  navSelector  : '.navigation-links',    // selector for the paged navigation 
  nextSelector : '.navigation-links a:first-of-type',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
  itemSelector : '.hentry',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
  loadingText : 'test',
  bufferpx : '80',
  loading: {
      finishedMsg: 'Thats the end of this gallery.',
      img: 'http://ryanswansondesign.com/wp-content/themes/ryan/images/ajax-loader.gif',
    }
  },
  // trigger Masonry as a callback
  function( newElements ) {
    // hide new items while they are loading
    var $newElems = $(newElements).css({ opacity: 0 });
    // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
      // show elems now they're ready
      $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
      $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
      hoverForTitles();
    });
  }
);
```

});

Comment: I did look there. I'm not a developer though, so it's hard for me to make sense of some of the documentation. I did realized that "loadingText" should be "msgText" but the bufferpx is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the '' around your '80' bufferpx value, otherwise you're passing it as a string. Also, you may want to look [on github here](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/145).